# Microphone not detected anymore after kernel change on Lenovo Ideapad 5 14ARE05

Tags: pulseaudio, lenovo, microphone, ideapad

After updating to kernel 5.7.0 under ubuntu 20.04 to be able to have support for my screen. (Before I could not adjust the brightness) it is now my microphone which doesn't seem to be recognized by my computer. However the sound still works.

In settings nothing is available, it doesn't recognize my airpods microphone neither although on the output side everyting is fine (I can hear music, calls ect...)

When I run:

```
pulseaudio -v
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.99.1
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 444fc26f472b46a0a63f493bc042d5e3.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/jeremie/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Most subs mention pavucontrol, but when I try to start it it stays blocked on "establishing connection to PulseAudio..."

Thanks in advance to anyone with some time and patience to help me with this :)

Have a great day

Comment: You haven't given details as to where you sourced your kernel (is it an *older* Ubuntu *test* kernel? or upstream?)  Does it have ubuntu-sauce added?  Why you didn't use the Ubuntu 5.8 kernel which will next go to *focal* (when it reaches 20.04.2) surprises me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works after updating to 5.8.1. However it is now my sound system which doesn't work.

Comment: I can listen to music and speak when my earpods are connected but I can't ouput sound through my computer's integrated speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @guiverc for your reply. After upgrading to kernel 5.8.1 my computer's integrated speakers do not work anymore.
My earpods however are recognized, I can talk and listen to music through my earpods' mics. However I cannot use my computer's mic and speakers.

```
> pulseaudio -v
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.99.1
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 444fc26f472b46a0a63f493bc042d5e3.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/jeremie/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Thanks